# How long do Black Flute repel and White Flute attract effects last?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

I walked a thousand steps through filthy ash to get Black Flute which is supposed to repel wild Pokémon. This is what it says:

> [image: Black Flute] A glass flute that keeps away wild POKéMON.

And the White one:

> [image: White Flute] A glass flute that lures wild POKéMON.

**I've read Bulbapedia on the topic**, but I'm not satisfied - it doesn't say how long the effect lasts.

I can't see any effect after using any of these. **How long do they last**?

Answer (score 3):

**Black Flute:**

> Reduces wild Pokémon encounter rate by 50%.

**White Flute:**

> Increases wild Pokémon encounter rate by 50%.

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Flute#List_of_Flutes).

---

Regarding the duration, there's a controversy about their effects.

As different people on *GameFaqs* suggests [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/921905-pokemon-emerald-version/43253350), [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/921905-pokemon-emerald-version/51338162) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/471243-pokemon-ruby-version/answers/360546-black-flute-repel-limits):

> White and Black Flutes should only work for *one step* each time they are played.

However, on [this forum](http://www.pokemasters.net/forums/showthread.php?t=8583) is explained that:

> The White Flute and Black Flutes raise and lower the encounter rate, respectively. They last *as long as you're in the general area you used it*.

Comment: How long do they last? I've read bulbapedia before asking of course.

Comment: Also seriously, did you just edit my question so that it fits information you have? That's straight vandalism

Comment: @TomášZato I've added the information you've requested. And no, I haven't changed your question to fit my answer, just a more generic title, because the word "repel" was misleading to me.

Comment: The posts claiming it's 1 step are all "I heard it somewhere," which is basically unsubstantiated rumor as far as the value of those statements goes. It's also completely illogical, since an item that worked like that would be _completely useless_. [This post](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/248285/how-long-do-the-effects-of-flutes-last) provides a proper experimental examination of its workings in ORAS, though still references those unhelpful "heard it somewhere" posts in regards to earlier games.

Comment: @MikeKellogg I get your point. I've found that post, too, but its examination is about ORAS and the OP is asking about 3rd gen games.

Comment: Seems I'll need to make some tests.

Answer (score 0):

They stop working as soon as you change screens (I. E. go through a door, enter a cave, etc.) I only know this for Emerald as it's the only one I've played, but I would be interested to hear the results for R/S and OR/AS.